# How to query the length of the boost::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++, boost, path

I couldn't find a 'path length' method in the [boost::filesystem::path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp), is there one?

If there is no such method (why?) - should I use .native().length() or .string().length() ?
I take it .string().length() should be faster, right?

Comment: I just need a length query on a path. I don't want to create a _different_ string while I'm doing that. It looks like string() potentially would do some conversions()  and native() would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.native()` directly returns the internal representation of the path, while `string()` might perform some conversions. All in all, it won't make much difference though whether you use `native().length()` or `string().length()`.

Comment: A point worth noting is that the `string` function will allocate a `std::string` object while `native` returns a (const) reference.

Answer (score 1):

How about string() method? (returns std::string)

```
fs::path path;
...
path.string().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no length on path and it doesn't really follow why you would want it.

`.string()` is the generally recommended thing to use for externally visible representations.  Check out the [path decomposition table](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Path-decomposition-table) in their docs to get that warm fuzzy reassurance on what to expect.

I have no reason to believe performance would differ with either.  You probably shouldn't worry about it until your profiler tells you to. :)

Comment: Yeah. On the other hand I see no point creating completely unnecessary strings containing an 'externally visible representation' while I only need to get a path length.

Comment: @Dimitry C You likely are creating them anyway.  The internal representation may not be a string at all, and the length of it would not be informative.  They support a lot of file systems that look very different.  Their reference specifically says to use `.string()` over `.native()` unless you have to.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/filesystem/v3/path.hpp and at least in the POSIX world both just return a reference to the internal string.  And in Windows .string() converts slashes. That's it.